# How to implement a barrier for sequential async Objectify save() operations in a loop

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify, appengine-pipeline

Our team has a GAE pipeline, in which a `GenerateJob` could generate and save a huge amount of `MyEntity`'s into Datastore. Currently the `save` operations in the `GenerateJob` are done sequentially and synchronously using `ofy().save().entity().now()` in a for loop. We'd like to improve the running time by changing the loop to `ofy().save().entity()` for async processing.

However, later in the pipeline we have another job that read all these entries and process them. How can we implement a barrier to wait for all the `save` operations? Will `ObjectifyFilter.complete()` work in this case? Something like this:

```java
public class JobA {
  public void generate(MyInput input) {
    for (MyEntity entity : processInput(input)) {
      // ... Additional work for entity.

      addResult(entity);
    }

    // Will ObjectifyFilter.complete() work as a barrier here?
  }

  public void addResult(MyEntity entity) {
    // Change to ofy().save().entity(entity) for async ops?
    ofy().save().entity(entity).now();
  }
}

public void JobB {
  public void someWorkOnMyEntities() {
    // Need to make sure all the previous save() operations are finished.
    Iterable<MyEntity> entities = ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class);
    // ... processing logic.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, have a look at `ofy().defer().save()`. That will batch up a bunch of save operations into a single bulk operation at the close of your transaction (or session). You may also call `flush()` periodically if you would like to finalize the current progress.

However, figuring out how to create some sort of write barrier among jobs across servers in a distributed system is non-trivial. Objectify doesn't provide any help, but Objectify is a low-level API. You'll need something at a much higher level that understands how your job queue works.